# BubbleChart with Callout

Tags: labeling, charts

I have following data

```
data={{{"MYCBP2", 7, 1.31161, 7}, {"F5", 6, 1.65189, 6}, {"IRF2BPL", 6, 
   1.65189, 6}, {"DMXL1", 6, 1.65189, 6}, {"MROH2B", 6, 1.65189, 
   6}, {"MACF1", 6, 1.65189, 6}, {"IRS4", 1, 1.31161, 1}, {"HECTD1", 
   6, 1.65189, 6}, {"KIAA0232", 6, 1.65189, 6}, {"CUBN", 8, 1.63422, 
   8}, {"PURB", 6, 1.65189, 6}, {"FHOD1", 0, 1.65189, 0}}, {{"CEP350",
    7, 2.01659, 7}, {"VPS13C", 7, 2.01659, 7}, {"SPEN", 6, 2.01795, 
   6}, {"DNAH3", 7, 2.01659, 7}, {"ERCC2", 9, 2.78759, 9}, {"ANK2", 9,
    2.78759, 9}, {"HERC1", 8, 2.39479, 8}, {"KRT4", 9, 2.78759, 
   9}, {"TYRO3", 1, 2.33592, 1}, {"KMT2C", 19, 6.72092, 19}, {"AKAP9",
    9, 2.78759, 9}}};
BubbleChart[data[[All, All, 2 ;; 4]]]
```

[image]

How can I apply `Callout`funtion to data? Note that some data are overlap so I want multiple callout to same bubble if possible. Bubble labels are first entry of data. Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you see the `Callout` examples under Scope -> Labeling and legending in the `BubbleChart` documentation?

Comment: Yes, I did. For some reason I couldn't figure it out. Same data point different label cause some problem I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing with your data, I saw some strange behaviors from Mathematica 12.2.

```
data = {{{"MYCBP2", 7, 1.31161, 7}, {"F5", 6, 1.65189, 6}, {"IRF2BPL",
      6, 1.65189, 6}, {"DMXL1", 6, 1.65189, 6}, {"MROH2B", 6, 1.65189,
      6}, {"MACF1", 6, 1.65189, 6}, {"IRS4", 1, 1.31161, 
     1}, {"HECTD1", 6, 1.65189, 6}, {"KIAA0232", 6, 1.65189, 
     6}, {"CUBN", 8, 1.63422, 8}, {"PURB", 6, 1.65189, 6}, {"FHOD1", 
     0, 1.65189, 0}}, {{"CEP350", 7, 2.01659, 7}, {"VPS13C", 7, 
     2.01659, 7}, {"SPEN", 6, 2.01795, 6}, {"DNAH3", 7, 2.01659, 
     7}, {"ERCC2", 9, 2.78759, 9}, {"ANK2", 9, 2.78759, 9}, {"HERC1", 
     8, 2.39479, 8}, {"KRT4", 9, 2.78759, 9}, {"TYRO3", 1, 2.33592, 
     1}, {"KMT2C", 19, 6.72092, 19}, {"AKAP9", 9, 2.78759, 9}}};
```

I use `Map` to make `Callout`:

```
data2 = Map[Callout[#[[2 ;; 4]], #[[1]]] &, data, {2}]
(*Out: {{Callout[{7, 1.31161, 7}, "MYCBP2"], ... }, {Callout[{7, 2.01659, 7}, "CEP350"], ... }} *)

BubbleChart[data2, LabelingSize -> 30]
```

The chart will be plotted but with some errors and no callout
[image]

### Solution

But If you change the bubble size of `{"FHOD1", 0, 1.65189, 0}` which is zero to a non-zero value for example `{"FHOD1", 0, 1.65189, 0.5}`, errors will disappear and everything works as expected.

[image]

### Problem

It looks like if you set bubble size to zero in any element of your data whether it's in `Callout` wrapper or not, Mathematica will not show any `Callout`. In Mathematica `BubbleChart` [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html) in Details section mentioned:

> The value z [bubble size] should be positive.

but it doesn't discuss Possible Issues of non-positive values.
For example, we have two element with non-zero bubble size wrapped in `Callout`:

```
data3 = {Callout[{3, 2, 2}, "test"], Callout[{3, 3, 3}, "test"]};

BubbleChart[data3]
```

[image]

If I add an element with zero value in bubble size, whether it's wrapped in `Callout` or not, all the callouts will disappear:

```
data4 = Append[data3, {1.5, 2, 0}];

data5 = Append[data3, Callout[{1.5, 2, 0}, "test"]];

BubbleChart[data4]

BubbleChart[data5]
```

Results of `BubbleChart` for `data4` and `data5` are the same:

[image]

It's also interesting that in the example above no error raised but in your case, it did.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is rather badly suited for display with `BubbleChart`. One problem is `{"FHOD1", 0, 1.65189, 0}` will never show up because its bubble will have zero radius and no area. Another problem is repeated labels make it impossible for `BubbleChart` to display callouts even when, as I do in this answer, they are combined into a single label for cases where the numberical data elements are identical. Because of the 2nd problem, my code will label the bubbles with tooltips. You can substitute `Callout` for `Tooltip` should want to see the problem callouts produces.

```
h[lbls_] := If[Length[lbls] == 1, lbls[[1]], StringJoin[Riffle[lbls, " : "]]]

gdat1 = GroupBy[data[[1]], #[[2 ;;]] & -> First, h];
bpdat1 = KeyValueMap[Tooltip[#1, #2] &, gdat1];
gdat2 = GroupBy[data[[2]], #[[2 ;;]] & -> First, h];
bpdat2 = KeyValueMap[Tooltip[#1, #2] &, gdat2];

Show[
  BubbleChart[bpdat2,
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 22}, {1.2, 7.4}}],
  BubbleChart[bpdat1,
    BubbleSizes -> {0.8, 2},
    ChartStyle -> ColorData[97][1],
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 22}, {1.2, 7.4}}]]
```

[image: chart]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, `Tooltip` does not help in my case since figure will be published eventually. I'll consider replacing 0 to some small amount say $10^{-10}$

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci. Replacing 0 with $10^-10$ wont make the bubble visible.